# Why do Kashiwara and Schapira require a base ring of finite global dimension?

Tags: reference-request, sheaf-theory, constructible-sheaves

In the book "Sheaves on Manifolds" by Kashiwara and Schapira, they work always with sheaves of $R$-modules, where $R$ is a ring of finite global dimension.

> > Why do they do this, what care must be taken when working similarly over a general base (are any of their theorems false?), and is there a reference which works over a general base ring?